# Any way to sync files from two parent directories, when their inside structure is different?

Tags: sync, shell

Lets say we have two directories:

Directory A:

```
aaa.mov
bbb.mov
ccc.mov
ddd.mov
eee.mov
```

Directory B:

```
subdir1/aaa.mov
subdir1/bbb.mov
subdir2/subsubdir/ccc.mov
```

How could I transfer from A to B/newDir, all files which do not exist under any B's subdirectories (ddd.mov & eee.mov)?

Comment: Judging from `/`, operating system is Linux or Mac OS X?

Comment: well..Mac OS X :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple shell script will achieve what you want...

```
#!/bin/sh

SRCDIR=dira
DSTDIR=dirb
SRCFILES=`find ${SRCDIR} -type f -exec basename '{}' \;`
mkdir -p ${DSTDIR}/NewDir

for FILE in ${SRCFILES}
do
        FOUND=`find ${DSTDIR} -name ${FILE} -type f`
        if [ -z ${FOUND} ]
        then
                echo -n "Copying ${FILE}..."
                cp ${SRCDIR}/${FILE} ${DSTDIR}/NewDir
                echo "done"
        fi
done
```